# SVG.JS - How to play + pause SVG animation on hover?

Tags: svg.js

How can I trigger and pause animations on an svg.js group element?
The following only triggers the animation on the first mouseover, but once I mouse over it a second time - the animation doesn't work.

```
 var group = draw.group(),
    circle = group.circle(diameter).fill(color);

group.on('mouseover', function() {
    circle.animate(3000, '-').scale(2).opacity(0).loop();
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    circle.pause();
});
```

Comment: You finished the animation. So its over and cleared from memory. You might want to move the animation code line to mouseover instead of declaring it before. But if you really only want to pause it, use `pause()` instead of `finish()`

Comment: @Fuzzyma thanks. I moved the animation under the mouseover function, and changed circle.finish() to circle.pause() -- however it still won't resume the animation when I mouseover the element for the 2nd time. See updated code in the original post.

Comment: That were 2 solution. Don't do both. That won't work!

Comment: @Fuzzyma ohhh! I understand. However, if I delete the 'mouseout' function and leave everything as is, then the animation plays indefinitely even after mousing out. If I remove the ".loop()" part from the mouseover, then it will stop once I mouseout, but won't retrigger the 2nd time I mouseover... am I still missing something?

Comment: Define the animation outside and pause it. Resume it on mouseover (play) and pause it on mouse out. Pretty straight forward!

Comment: @Fuzzyma haha ok thanks got it!!!

Comment: @Fuzzyma Can I ask a follow up related question -- do you know if there's a way to get the animation .finish() effect without it clearing the animation memory? The scale/opacity animation when it pauses abruptly looks strange on mouseout. I want the circle element to go back to its original state before the scale transformation happened. I liked that finish() finished the animation nicely....but need it to indefinitely repeat on every mouseover.

Comment: In that case you want the first solution. You define the animation in mouseover and finish it in mouse out. Whenever you mouseover, a new animation is created

Comment: @Fuzzyma you are an angel. I finally feel like I better understand how the library works. I ended up having the animation on loop in mouseover, and then in mouseout use pause() chained with scale(1).opacity(1) to get it back to the element's original state. TY!